# $a\vee b$ and $a\wedge b$ have complements. Does $a$ have one?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\le)$ be a bounded lattice and $a,b\in X$ and $a\vee b$ and $a\wedge b$ have complements. Do $a$ and $b$ have complements necessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider the $7$-element lattice consisting of the numbers $1,2,3,5,6,10,30$ ordered by divisibility. Now $2\vee3=6$ has a unique complement, namely $5$; and $2\wedge3=1$ has a unique complement, namely $30$; and $3$ has two complements, $5$ and $10$; but $2$ has no complement at all.

Comment: Let me check if $a$ is a complement of $2$ then $a\wedge 2=1$ so it is odd and $a\vee 2=30$ how about $a=15$?

Comment: 15 is not an element of my **7**-element lattice.

Comment: yep; it seems to be a lattice really, let me check again: 30 is an upper bound for every 2 elements and the upper bounds are finite so there have to be a least one which is a supremum. similarly for infimum. And it is a poset because it is a subset of a poset. again if $a$ is a complement of $2$ then $a∧2=1$ so 2 does not divide $a$ and it is odd. As subset of a lattice $a\vee 2=30$ so $a$ divides $30=15\times 2$, $a$ divides $15$. $a$ is not $1$ or $3$ ($2\vee 3=6$) of $a=5$ ($2\vee 5=10$). So $a$ is nothing. seems correct.

Comment: I'm not sure you really checked that it's a lattice. You have to show that any two elements have a **least** upper bound (as well as a greatest lower bound), which is **not** immediate from 30 being a greatest element. In fact, the meets and joins are **mostly** the same as in the 8-element Boolean algebra (before I removed 15); the exception is that $3\vee5=30$ in my 7-element lattice.

Comment: Yes. I said 30 is an upper bound so we have at least one. we have finitely many others. So there is a minimal upper bound. Yes. existence of "minimal" is proved while I need existence of "minimum".

Comment: Right. Note, for example, that the set $\{1,2,3,12,18,36\}$ ordered by divisibility is **not** a lattice order.

Comment: Let me rethink: if $x\vee y= 15$ in $D_{30}$, then 30 is the only upper bound of $x$ and $y$ in the deleted lattice. so it is the least upper bound. if $x\wedge y = 15$ then $x,y\in \{15,30\}$ so they have an infimum which is one of them. It seems clear existence and value of other infs and sups are intact.

Comment: My work here is done.